# How to access a class which is in a folder c# (wpf)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building a WPF application. I'm almost finished with one part of it, and now I want to clean up the code a bit. English is not my native language (so sorry if this gets marked as a duplicate) and I couldn't find anything about this, so I hope someone can help me out.

If I have public voids in a class called 'class.cs' and this class is in a folder called 'classes', how do I access the class so I can use its functions?

Comment: Open the code file for the class you want to access. Look for "namespace MyNameSpaceName" at the top of the file. You can access the class via "MyNameSpaceName.MyClassName".

Comment: Is it in your project? Have you specified the full namespace when using or added a `using` for the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the file where you want to use the class include a using statement.

```
using [namespace];
```

Then you will be able to instantiate the class

```
Class testClass = new Class();
testClass.Method();
```

If you aren't sure what the namespace for your Class class is, then you can write the line to instantiate the class and then use the intellisense (assuming you are using a development ide like Visual Studio) to automatically include the reference.  Alternatively, you can look at the top of your class.cs file to see what namespace has been declared.

Answer (score 0):

check what namespace it's in , then what the class name is and call it as 
"Namespace.class"
in case that you can't see it still , check if the class is public and the class.cs properties have the build property set to compile

Comment: It might be worth adding whether the method is static or not... if the method is an instance method, then they would need to instantiate the class to use it.

Comment: Yes i wasn't assuming it might be static function up there , that worth adding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from where You are trying to access this class. But I think the easiest way of doing it probably will be just typing your class name in place where You are trying to use it and press 'ctrl+.' which should show You context menu with options to add using statement for this class. 
If You are trying to access this class from other project in solution then above way will only work with VS2017(because it will also add missing project reference) otherwise You need to add reference for this project and then add missing using statement for your class(in your case 'using ProjectName.classes').

Answer (score 0):

The folder you are talking about is called a namespace. You first need to import the namespace and then you can use your class.

*Normally the IDE will prompt you.